# Laravel Feature Testing. Cache mocking not working! CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations were specified

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, phpunit, laravel-5.8

When I test my application with unit-testing cache moking works well. But when I try test my api through feature tests I got an exception.

```
public function testGet()
{
    Cache::shouldReceive('rememberForever')->times(5)->andReturn([]);

    Cache::shouldReceive('has')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(false);

    Cache::shouldReceive('forever')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn([]);

    $response = $this->getJson('/api/table/get');
    $response->assertOk();

    $responseArr = $response->getOriginalContent();
    $this->assertEmpty($responseArr['table']);
}
```

> Tests\Feature\Controller\API\Site\TableApiControllerTest::testGet
>   Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received
>   Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations
>   were specified

Exactly the same mocking in other unit-tests works without errors.

Comment: I guess you have already done it, but I would check the same code is executing by die-dumping something before the Cache gets called to ensure that it is a Mocking problem. Is the actual Cache getting touched?

Comment: dd(123); before Cache works without exceptions

Comment: Are you overriding some env variables on your `phpunit.xml` file?

Comment: only DB_CONNECTION

Answer (score 3):

I found answer here - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10803#issuecomment-401611084%23issuecomment-401611084

```
    $cacheDriver = app('cache')->driver();
    Cache::shouldReceive('driver')->andReturn($cacheDriver);
```