# Cache mock exception after update Laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel-6

I have unit tests with Cache mocks. It worked well before update laravel to 6.0

After update I ran my tests and got an exception

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException: Received
>   Mockery_2_Illuminate_Cache_CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations
>   were specified

```
    Cache::shouldReceive('get')
        ->once()
        ->with('table_3_'.config('constants.league.premier').'_'.config('constants.sex.female'))
        ->andReturn(json_encode([
            [
                'id' => $team1->id,
                'place' => 1
            ],
            [
                'id' => $team2->id,
                'place' => 8
            ],
            [
                'id' => $team3->id,
                'place' => 11
            ],
        ]));

    $this->artisan('passport:transfer');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer here - [Laravel Feature Testing. Cache mocking not working! CacheManager::driver(), but no expectations were specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56234834/laravel-feature-testing-cache-mocking-not-working-cachemanagerdriver-but)

but I don't understand why before update the test was ok